# Optimize if statement in R

Tags: r

I have this piece of code, although it works - it takes quite sometime to process (7 minutes) of 530,000 records in my data.frame.

My aim is to create a field in my frame and populate it based on the value of people$Month as shown below:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(people)) {
  if(people$Month[i]=='JAN') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "1"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='FEB') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "2"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='MAR') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "3"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='APR') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "4"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='MAY') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "5"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='JUN') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "6"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='JUL') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "7"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='AUG') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "8"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='SEP') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "9"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='OCT') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "10"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='NOV') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "11"
  }
  else if(people$Month[i]=='DEC') {
    people[i, 'new_month'] <- "12"
  }
}
```

Is there any other way I can do this without lots of if statements as I've done here?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use a lookuptable with match, or have several ifelse statements (something you want to avoid I guess). You could also use a join.

Comment: Use match. No need to loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match` is the way I would go here.

```
M <- sample(month.abb, size = 300, replace = TRUE)

people <- data.frame(Month = toupper(M))

people$new_month <- match(people$Month, toupper(month.abb))

head(people)
```

Doing this on a random selection of 530,000 month names is taking me about 10 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will give it a try and let you know. This looks like a way to go.